# export defect details from quality center and update it on Oracle DB

Tags: oracle11g, batch-processing, hp-quality-center

I want an an automated batch job, that runs nightly, that downloads specific columns from QC(defects) with a set of filters and then update the data on to an Oracle database. Which scripting language would you suggest to look in to?
Any input will be of great help!

Thanks,
Ramya

Answer (score 0):

First you have to decide which Quality Center API you like to use. The REST API or the OTA API. Using REST you can use nearly any language you want. Using the OTA API you need a language which supports COM objects. The examples in the OTA API documentation use VB. Personally I prefer Ruby to access Quality Center via the OTA API. Here is an example of how to connect to Quality Center and retrieve open bugs:

```
require 'win32ole'
tdc = WIN32OLE.new('TDApiOle80.TDConnection')
tdc.InitConnectionEx('https://yourserver/qcbin/')
tdc.Login('user', 'pass')
tdc.Connect('domain', 'project')
bug_factory = tdc.BugFactory
bug_filter = bug_factory.Filter
bug_filter["BG_STATUS"] = 'Open'
bugs = bug_factory.NewList(bug_filter)
```

You can also connect to Oracle using Ruby, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892301/connecting-to-oracle-db-using-ruby).